# Cross-compiling for Raspberry Pi: can't find bits/c++config.h

Tags: c++, c++11, raspberry-pi, cross-compiling, raspbian

I'm trying to setup a c++ 11 cross-compiler (version 4.9.2-r2) for the raspberry pi (Raspbian-jessie) on windows 7 x64.
I am working in CodeLite and I added the cross compiler under settings->build settings. I've also set the compiler as the one to use for my project.

The problem I am having is this error:

```
c:\sysgcc\raspberry\arm-linux-gnueabihf\include\c++\4.9\iostream:38:28: fatal error: bits/c++config.h: No such file or directory
#include <bits/c++config.h>
```

I searched on the internet for this problem but I am only finding people who are trying to cross compile for 64 bit linux on a 32 bit version or visa versa but nothing related to the Pi.

**Edit 1:**
As requested in the comments, this is the complete output when I compile with the -v option:

```
C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /C mingw32-make -e -f  Makefile
"----------Building project:[ TestProject01 - Release ]----------"
mingw32-make[1]: Entering directory 'C:/Users/Peter/Downloads/THO6/github_repo/product/test_product/TestProject/TestProject01'
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=C:/SysGCC/Raspberry/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++.exe
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=c:/sysgcc/raspberry/bin/../libexec/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.9/lto-wrapper.exe
Target: arm-linux-gnueabihf
Configured with: ../gcc-4.9.2/src/configure --enable-win32-registry=SysGCC-arm-linux-gnueabihf-4.9.2 --prefix /q/gnu/linux/raspberry-jessie/out/ --disable-nls --without-libiconv-prefix --with-sysroot=/q/gnu/linux/raspberry-jessie/out/arm-linux-gnueabihf/sysroot --enable-languages=c,c++ --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-libitm --disable-libquadmath --with-arch-directory=arm --disable-sjlj-exceptions --with-arch=armv6 --with-fpu=vfp --with-float=hard --enable-checking=release --target arm-linux-gnueabihf
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.9.2 (GCC)
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-std=c++11' '-O2' '-Wall' '-v' '-D' 'NDEBUG' '-I' '.' '-I' '.' '-MG' '-MP' '-MT' './Release/main.cpp.o' '-MF' './Release/main.cpp.o.d' '-MM' '-shared-libgcc' '-march=armv6' '-mfloat-abi=hard' '-mfpu=vfp' '-mtls-dialect=gnu'
 c:/sysgcc/raspberry/bin/../libexec/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.9/cc1plus.exe -E -quiet -v -I . -I . -imultilib . -imultiarch arm-linux-gnueabihf -iprefix c:\sysgcc\raspberry\bin\../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.9/ -isysroot c:\sysgcc\raspberry\bin\../arm-linux-gnueabihf/sysroot -MM -MF ./Release/main.cpp.o.d -MG -MP -MT ./Release/main.cpp.o -D_GNU_SOURCE -D NDEBUG main.cpp -march=armv6 -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=vfp -mtls-dialect=gnu -std=c++11 -Wall -O2
ignoring nonexistent directory "c:\sysgcc\raspberry\bin\../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.9/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf/c++/4.9/arm-linux-gnueabihf"
ignoring duplicate directory "c:/sysgcc/raspberry/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.9/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/include/c++/4.9"
ignoring nonexistent directory "C:/MinGW/msys/1.0/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf/c++/4.9/."
ignoring nonexistent directory "c:/sysgcc/raspberry/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.9/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf/c++/4.9"
ignoring duplicate directory "c:/sysgcc/raspberry/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.9/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/include/c++/4.9/backward"
ignoring duplicate directory "c:/sysgcc/raspberry/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.9/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "c:\sysgcc\raspberry\bin\../arm-linux-gnueabihf/sysroot/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf/arm-linux-gnueabihf"
ignoring duplicate directory "c:/sysgcc/raspberry/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.9/include-fixed"
ignoring duplicate directory "c:/sysgcc/raspberry/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.9/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/include"
ignoring duplicate directory "c:\sysgcc\raspberry\bin\../arm-linux-gnueabihf/sysroot/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf"
ignoring duplicate directory "."
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 .
 c:\sysgcc\raspberry\bin\../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.9/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/include/c++/4.9
 c:\sysgcc\raspberry\bin\../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.9/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/include/c++/4.9/backward
 c:\sysgcc\raspberry\bin\../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.9/include
 c:\sysgcc\raspberry\bin\../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.9/include-fixed
 c:\sysgcc\raspberry\bin\../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.9/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/include
 c:\sysgcc\raspberry\bin\../arm-linux-gnueabihf/sysroot/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf
 c:\sysgcc\raspberry\bin\../arm-linux-gnueabihf/sysroot/usr/include
End of search list.
COMPILER_PATH=c:/sysgcc/raspberry/bin/../libexec/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.9/;c:/sysgcc/raspberry/bin/../libexec/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/;c:/sysgcc/raspberry/bin/../libexec/gcc/;c:/sysgcc/raspberry/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.9/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/
LIBRARY_PATH=c:/sysgcc/raspberry/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.9/;c:/sysgcc/raspberry/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/;c:/sysgcc/raspberry/bin/../lib/gcc/;c:/sysgcc/raspberry/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.9/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/lib/;c:/sysgcc/raspberry/bin/../arm-linux-gnueabihf/sysroot/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/;c:/sysgcc/raspberry/bin/../arm-linux-gnueabihf/sysroot/lib/;c:/sysgcc/raspberry/bin/../arm-linux-gnueabihf/sysroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/;c:/sysgcc/raspberry/bin/../arm-linux-gnueabihf/sysroot/usr/lib/
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-std=c++11' '-O2' '-Wall' '-v' '-D' 'NDEBUG' '-I' '.' '-I' '.' '-MG' '-MP' '-MT' './Release/main.cpp.o' '-MF' './Release/main.cpp.o.d' '-MM' '-shared-libgcc' '-march=armv6' '-mfloat-abi=hard' '-mfpu=vfp' '-mtls-dialect=gnu'
C:/SysGCC/Raspberry/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++.exe  -c  "C:/Users/Peter/Downloads/THO6/github_repo/product/test_product/TestProject/TestProject01/main.cpp" -std=c++11 -O2 -Wall -v -DNDEBUG  -o ./Release/main.cpp.o -I. -I.
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=C:/SysGCC/Raspberry/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++.exe
Target: arm-linux-gnueabihf
Configured with: ../gcc-4.9.2/src/configure --enable-win32-registry=SysGCC-arm-linux-gnueabihf-4.9.2 --prefix /q/gnu/linux/raspberry-jessie/out/ --disable-nls --without-libiconv-prefix --with-sysroot=/q/gnu/linux/raspberry-jessie/out/arm-linux-gnueabihf/sysroot --enable-languages=c,c++ --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-libitm --disable-libquadmath --with-arch-directory=arm --disable-sjlj-exceptions --with-arch=armv6 --with-fpu=vfp --with-float=hard --enable-checking=release --target arm-linux-gnueabihf
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.9.2 (GCC)
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-c' '-std=c++11' '-O2' '-Wall' '-v' '-D' 'NDEBUG' '-o' './Release/main.cpp.o' '-I' '.' '-I' '.' '-shared-libgcc' '-march=armv6' '-mfloat-abi=hard' '-mfpu=vfp' '-mtls-dialect=gnu'
 c:/sysgcc/raspberry/bin/../libexec/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.9/cc1plus.exe -quiet -v -I . -I . -imultilib . -imultiarch arm-linux-gnueabihf -iprefix c:\sysgcc\raspberry\bin\../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.9/ -isysroot c:\sysgcc\raspberry\bin\../arm-linux-gnueabihf/sysroot -D_GNU_SOURCE -D NDEBUG C:/Users/Peter/Downloads/THO6/github_repo/product/test_product/TestProject/TestProject01/main.cpp -quiet -dumpbase main.cpp -march=armv6 -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=vfp -mtls-dialect=gnu -auxbase-strip ./Release/main.cpp.o -O2 -Wall -std=c++11 -version -o C:\Users\Peter\AppData\Local\Temp\ccjXLoID.s
GNU C++ (GCC) version 4.9.2 (arm-linux-gnueabihf)
    compiled by GNU C version 4.8.1, GMP version 4.2.4, MPFR version 2.4.1, MPC version 0.8
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
ignoring nonexistent directory "c:\sysgcc\raspberry\bin\../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.9/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf/c++/4.9/arm-linux-gnueabihf"
ignoring duplicate directory "c:/sysgcc/raspberry/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.9/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/include/c++/4.9"
ignoring nonexistent directory "C:/MinGW/msys/1.0/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf/c++/4.9/."
ignoring nonexistent directory "c:/sysgcc/raspberry/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.9/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf/c++/4.9"
ignoring duplicate directory "c:/sysgcc/raspberry/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.9/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/include/c++/4.9/backward"
ignoring duplicate directory "c:/sysgcc/raspberry/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.9/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "c:\sysgcc\raspberry\bin\../arm-linux-gnueabihf/sysroot/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf/arm-linux-gnueabihf"
ignoring duplicate directory "c:/sysgcc/raspberry/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.9/include-fixed"
ignoring duplicate directory "c:/sysgcc/raspberry/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.9/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/include"
ignoring duplicate directory "c:\sysgcc\raspberry\bin\../arm-linux-gnueabihf/sysroot/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf"
ignoring duplicate directory "."
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 .
 c:\sysgcc\raspberry\bin\../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.9/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/include/c++/4.9
 c:\sysgcc\raspberry\bin\../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.9/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/include/c++/4.9/backward
 c:\sysgcc\raspberry\bin\../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.9/include
 c:\sysgcc\raspberry\bin\../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.9/include-fixed
 c:\sysgcc\raspberry\bin\../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.9/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/include
 c:\sysgcc\raspberry\bin\../arm-linux-gnueabihf/sysroot/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf
 c:\sysgcc\raspberry\bin\../arm-linux-gnueabihf/sysroot/usr/include
End of search list.
GNU C++ (GCC) version 4.9.2 (arm-linux-gnueabihf)
    compiled by GNU C version 4.8.1, GMP version 4.2.4, MPFR version 2.4.1, MPC version 0.8
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
Compiler executable checksum: 77a52a28e20292d776f27f30cc5b625f
In file included from C:/Users/Peter/Downloads/THO6/github_repo/product/test_product/TestProject/TestProject01/main.cpp:2:0:
c:\sysgcc\raspberry\arm-linux-gnueabihf\include\c++\4.9\iostream:38:28: fatal error: bits/c++config.h: No such file or directory
 #include <bits/c++config.h>
                            ^
compilation terminated.
mingw32-make[1]: *** [Release/main.cpp.o] Error 1
TestProject01.mk:97: recipe for target 'Release/main.cpp.o' failed
mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/Peter/Downloads/THO6/github_repo/product/test_product/TestProject/TestProject01'
mingw32-make: *** [All] Error 2
Makefile:4: recipe for target 'All' failed
====2 errors, 1 warnings====
```

Comment: You may install virtual Ubuntu and cross-compile there with gcc.

Comment: If you compile with a -v option, what include paths are shown? Does a bits/c++config.h exist there?

Comment: @RichardPennington I've added the info to my question

Comment: On my Pi, c++config.h is in ./arm-linux-gnueabihf/c++/4.9/bits/c++config.h so I'm assuming yours should be in c:\sysgcc\raspberry\bin\../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.9/include/bits is it? Do you have a small source file? I can try to compile it with ELLCC (http://ellcc.org).

Comment: @RichardPennington I found the file in `C:\SysGCC\Raspberry\arm-linux-gnueabihf\sysroot\usr\include\arm-linux-gnueabihf\c++\4.9\bits`. Manually including the file into my project (either by adding its dir as an include path or by copying it to the default include path) doesn't work. Even just a simple Hello World that includes <iostream> does not compile.